# How to use a variable in a min statement in R?

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, min

I am creating a variable that will contain the name of a column in a data frame.  I can then use the variable to return the column from the data frame.  However when I use the variable as part of a min statement it errors.  Hopefully this example has enough information to answer this, basically I'm trying to get one of the last 2 statements to work:

```
outcome <- "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack" #my column name variable
singlemetric[outcome] #returns the column using the variable
min(singlemetric$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack,na.rm = TRUE) #this works

min(singlemetric$outcome,na.rm = TRUE) # this returns inf no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
min(singlemetric$[outcome],na.rm = TRUE) #also doesn't work Error: unexpected '[' in min(singlemetric$["
```

Comment: you're looking for `singlemetric[[outcome]]`

Comment: If you had shorter column names you could then easily use the `$` operator with the name :)

Answer (score 2):

The comment by Ben Bolker worked as a solution:

```
singlemetric[[outcome]]
```

Comment: Alternatively `singlemetric[, outcome]`, or as @Nikos says `singlemetric[outcome]`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
min(singlemetric$outcome,na.rm = TRUE)
```

Assumes there is a column named 'outcome'. Can you try:

```
min(singlemetric[outcome],na.rm = TRUE)
```

and see if it works? In any case, the comment by @ben-bolker also works.